# JavaScript Module Pattern in a Image Slider

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to JavaScript and I wanted to try making a image slider. I ended up making a basic one from following a couple tutorials and I've got it working, but I want it to be in an external js file (which it already is) and I know that you want to use a module pattern to make 'private' variables.

How would I put this into a module pattern? Here's what I have so far:

slider.js

```
(function() {
    var images = ['img/1.png', 'img/2.png', 'img/3.jpg'];

    var imgNum = 0;
    var imgLength = images.length -1;

    function changeImage(direction) {
        imgNum = imgNum + direction;
        if (imgNum > imgLength) {
            imgNum = 0;
        }
        if (imgNum < 0) {
            imgNum = 2;
        }

        document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[imgNum];
        return false;
    }

    window.setInterval(function() {
        changeImage(1);
    }, 30000);

    return {
        //Not sure what to put here
    }
})();
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='style.css'>
        <script src="slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/1.png" alt='football1' id='slideshow'>
        <a href="#" onclick="return changeImage(-1)">Previous</a><br/>
        <a href="#" onclick="return changeImage(1)">Next</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/FSD45/)***

In order to modify this to use the module pattern, a few changes would have to be made. It is best practice to avoid inline javascript. A better way to mark the handler would be to use a class name.

Lets say that we will use "next" and "prev" as class names for the buttons

```
<a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

First we will initiate the slider module

```
var slider = (function(){
 var images = ['img/1.png', 'img/2.png', 'img/3.jpg'];

 var imgNum = 0;
 var imgLength = images.length -1;

 function changeImage(direction) {
    imgNum = imgNum + direction;
    if (imgNum > imgLength) {
        imgNum = 0;
    }
    if (imgNum < 0) {
        imgNum = 2;
    }

    document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[imgNum];
 }

 window.setInterval(function() {
  changeImage(1);
 }, 30000);

 return {
  next: function(){ changeImage(1); },
  prev: function(){ changeImage(-1); }
 };
})();
```

Now that it is initialized, when everything is loaded we can hook up some event handlers that will call the module

```
window.onload = function(){
 var nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".next");
 for( var i = 0, len = nextButtons.length; i<len; i++ ){
  nextButtons[i].onclick = function(){ slider.next(); };
 }
 var prevButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".prev");
 for( var i = 0, len = prevButtons.length; i<len; i++ ){
  prevButtons[i].onclick = function(){ slider.prev(); };
 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a module type of situation. If you wanted to use a module, it would make sense that it is going to be called mostly from other code and not just a simple inline call to an event handler.

As written, your code will not properly work because the function `changeImage` is not scoped globally and as such the anchor element will not have access to it. All you need to change from this code is to expose the `changeImage` function to the global scope. And since this is a rather simple scenario, there is nothing wrong with just attaching it to `window` and moving on.

```
window.changeImage = function(direction) {
  //code
};
```

Another thing to note here, is that when using an IIFE (Immediately executing function expression) without assignment there is no need to return a value. The returned value, regardless of what was in there, will go ununsed since there was no variable to hold it.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Yes, I will edit that. I was speaking to when it was used in this fashion but they are very useful for assignments.

Comment: I thought you meant that, I was just afraid the OP could misunderstand it. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
var Koy = (function(publicAPI) {

    publicAPI.imageSlider = function(images) {
        // initialize the slideshow here
    };

    var privateVariable = "I'm a private variable!";

    var privateFunction = function() {
        // this is a private method
    };

    publicAPI.publicVariable = "I'm a public variable!"

    publicAPI.publicMethod = function() {
        alert(privateVariable);
    };

    return publicAPI;

})(Koy || {});
```

Now from outside of this file you can do:

```
var slideshow = new Koy.imageSlider('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg');
```

What I did here is a variation of the module pattern which creates a namespace called "Koy". Inside the closure I created an object called publicAPI which will be ...wait for it... your public API. Anything that you want to be public gets added to that object. At the end of the module you return that object, thereby exposing it and making everything inside of it available. For the things that you want to be private, you simply declare them as variables and do nothing more. Items created inside of a closure are automatically "private."

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but that's really cool! I may like that better then the typical way of doing modules.

Comment: The only thing non-standard here is passing the publicAPI object in to the closure and adding it to a Koy namespace. If you remove "PublicAPI" from the anonymous function and "Koy || {}" from the invocation, you have a "standard" module. You would then add var publicAPI = {}; to the beginning of the closure. If you're not passing in the images to initiate the slider there is no point to making it a module B/C the code is not reusable. In that case, just use the IIFE and call it a day. BTW, the object that I called "publicAPI" is often named "my" in tutorials. Obs you can call it what you like